# What is the default access mode of files created with open() function in C?

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I wrote the following C code to open a non-existent file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int main(){
    int fd = open("test.c",O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
    printf("%d\n",fd);
    close(fd);
}
```

Although the umask is set to 0002 when I run the `ls -l` command, I get the following output for the file I created.

```
-r--rws--T 1 urohit011 urohit011     0 Feb 14 22:35 test.c
```

The access mode changes when I run the code with a new file name. I have two questions here.

- Shouldn't the default access mode of that file be 664 since the umask
  is 0002 ?
- Why the access mode changes when the code is run with a new    file
  name ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `"test.c"` as the filename? I hope you're not overwriting your source file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do not think the name "test.c" should be a problem as it does not exist before executing the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mode` / permission bits are specified by the third argument of [`open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) call. You do not provide that argument and that is a silent programming error when `O_CREAT` is used:

> This argument (`mode`) must be supplied when `O_CREAT` or `O_TMPFILE` is specified in `flags`; if neither `O_CREAT` nor `O_TMPFILE` is specified, then `mode` is ignored.

---

> Shouldn't the default access mode of that file be 664 since the umask is `0002`

Default `mode` must be explicitly provided:

```
open("test.c",O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666)
                                   ^^
```

---

> Why the access mode changes when the code is run with a new file name ?

`open` is a [variadic function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) that accepts 2 or more arguments:

```
int open(const char* file, int flag, ...);
```

Hence, the third argument of the function gets initialized with an indeterminate value if no value is provided. There is no compiler error if only 2 arguments are provided. On the other hand, it is not an error to always provide the third argument to `open` call.

Comment: The documenttion you yourself cite clearly shows that said third argument is _optional_.

Comment: @arkascha Really? _This argument must be supplied when `O_CREAT` or `O_TMPFILE` is specified in flags; if neither `O_CREAT` nor `O_TMPFILE` is specified, then mode is ignored._

Comment: Ah, thanks, my bad. I took your answer literal and absolute, since you made no such remark in it.

Comment: Got it @MaximEgorushkin, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The access mode on a file created must be specified on the `open(2)` call as the third parameter to it.  Because of the way C does things, that third parameter (allowed depending on flags used in the second parameter) makes the `open(2)` call variadic, and the compiler doesn't check if you have provided the right number of parameters.

Due to this, if you don't pass a third parameter, it will not be pushed onto the stack by the calling code, but the function will use whatever is there in the position for the third parameter.  You got a Undefined Behaviour issue, with the best result being getting a new file with the wrong access mode.  You can get a crash if the `open(2)` routine modifies the third parameter.

The access mode you provide will be finally modified by the `umask` bits to get the final mode of the created file.